# How to access selection options in material mat-selection-list

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to access the selected options of a material mat-selection-list component (version 7). I have found documentation for selectedOptions [here](https://material.angular.io/components/list/api#MatSelectionList).

I have fiddeld together some lines of html/ts that seem to give me access to the desired data. However I do not think it is the right way. However I could not find advice using "famous search engine".

I have folloing HTML (pizza.component.html)

```
<h1>Pizzas</h1>
<mat-selection-list #pizzaList (selectionChange)="onPizzasChange($event)">
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let pizza of pizzas">
        {{pizza}}
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

And corresponding typescript file (pizza.component.ts)

```
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { Pizza } from '../pizza';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-pizza-view',
    templateUrl: './pizza-view.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./pizza-view.component.css']
})

export class PizzaViewComponent implements OnInit {

    pizzas: any;

    constructor( ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        pizzas = [ 'Margherita', 'Funghi', 'Quattro Stagioni', 'Calzone' ];
    }

    onPizzasChange(event) {
        console.log("selectedOptions:", event.option.selectionList.selectedOptions._selection;
    };

}
```

Question would be: How do I do it correctly?

PS: I am using @angular/core 7.0.0 and material 7.0.1

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Start by adding a `value` for strings or `ngValue` for objects to your options.

```html
<mat-list-option *ngFor="let pizza of pizzas" [value]="pizza"> or [ngValue]="pizza"
```

#### Option 1: Using `selectionChange`

Pass the array of the selected MatListOptions to your function.

```html
<mat-selection-list #pizzaList (selectionChange)="onGroupsChange(pizzaList.selectedOptions.selected)">
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let pizza of pizzas" [value]="pizza">
        {{pizza}}
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

You will get an array that contains the selected options in the order they were selected.

```ts
import { MatListOption } from '@angular/material/list'

onGroupsChange(options: MatListOption[]) {
  // map these MatListOptions to their values
  console.log(options.map(o => o.value));
}
```

---

#### Option 2: Using `ngModel`

As @Eliseo commented you could use `ngModel` for 2-way data binding if you only want access to the selected data but don't need to be notified about changes.

```html
<mat-selection-list #pizzaList [(ngModel)]="selectedPizzas">
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let pizza of pizzas" [value]="pizza">
        {{pizza}}
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

```js
selectedPizzas: string[]; // this array will contain the selected pizzas
```

To additionally get notified about changes you could add `ngModelChange`:

```html
<mat-selection-list #pizzaList [(ngModel)]="selectedPizzas" (ngModelChange)="onGroupsChange($event)">
```

You will get an array that contains the selected options' values in the order they appear in the input array `pizzas` (not in the order they were selected as with `selectionChange`).

```ts
onGroupsChange(selectedPizzas: string[]) {
  console.log(selectedPizzas);
}
```

Comment: Why use (selectionChange)? you can do the same using [(ngModel)] -or using reactive Form-, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qcxfbe?file=app/list-selection-example.ts

Comment: @Eliseo If you just want access to the value array `[(ngModel)]` is simpler, you're right. I thought the OP wanted a function to be called on model changes. You could use `ngModelChange` additionally but that wouldn't make much difference to `selectionChange`. Reactive Forms are a bit more complex and as the question doesn't say whether the OP needs the extra functionality that comes with reactive forms I didn't suggest them.

Comment: Option 2 made the most sense and provided the exact results I was looking for.Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Well, IMHO, the right way seems to be using the `selectedOptions` property of the  `MatSelectionList`.

```
selectedOptions: SelectionModel<MatListOption>
```

In your example you're accessing a private property.
You can check out the sources of `SelectionModel` to see what you're able to use.

The right method seems to be

```
/** Selected values. */
get selected(): T[] {
  if (!this._selected) {
    this._selected = Array.from(this._selection.values());
  }

  return this._selected;
}
```

The event is typed as `MatSelectionListChange`, so:

```
onPizzasChange(event: MatSelectionListChange) {
    console.log("selectedOptions:", event.source.selectedOptions.selected();
};
```

PS: unlike the other answer, I prefer keeping the template as clean as possible.

All the properties accesses might be done inside the component. Which is also easier to read and understand.